# HTML/Javascript/jQuery page has a feature that works in one state but not another state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a strange thing happening with a part of a page working at one time, and not working in a different state of the page.

Take a look at this page:
http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=216

If you click on "Mobile App That Helps Stop or Curb Stress Eating" it will expand that into a bunch of forms.  That is how this page is supposed to work.

Now if you try to suggest a new solution by clicking "Suggest a Solution" you will get a form to make one.  After you fill out the form, the system shows you the previously present suggested solutions plus yours, but the problem is that if you click on any of them, the page will go to the same url with the # at the end of it, so something seems off.

To reproduce filling out the form, you need test login credentials:

```
login: testing@problemio.com
password testing
```

Here is the function on the server side that prints the contents of that div:

```
function printSuggestedSolutions ( $suggested_solutions_result )
{
    if (mysql_num_rows($suggested_solutions_result) > 0 )
    {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($suggested_solutions_result))
            {
                $suggested_solution_id = $row['suggested_solution_id'];
                $problem_id = $row['problem_id'];
                $solution = $row['solution']; 
                $solution_name = $row['solution_name']; 


                $day = $row['DAYOFMONTH(solution_date)'];
                $day_name = $row['DAYNAME(solution_date)'];
                $year = $row['YEAR(solution_date)'];
                $month = $row['MONTH(solution_date)'];

                $first_name = $row['first_name'];                
                $last_name = $row['last_name'];
                $email = $row['email'];                

                $formatted_date = $day_name.', '.$month.'-'.$day.'-'.$year;

                $suggester_id = $row['suggester_id'];               

                $solution = nl2br($solution);   

                // Have to make the better name and picture thing.
                $photo_path = $row['photo_path'];                
                $small_thumb = $row['small_thumb'];
                $mid_thumb = $row['mid_thumb'];       

                if ( isset ( $mid_thumb ) )
                {
                    $img_src = $mid_thumb;
                }
                else
                {
                    $img_src = "http://www.problemio.com/img/happy.jpg";
                }                                      

                echo '<div>';                  
                echo '<div style="padding-top: 15px; float:left; width: 150px;">';
                                echo '<img src='.$img_src.' width="100" >';
                    echo '<p>Comment by: <br />'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.'</p>';                                
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div style="float:left; width: 540px; ">';                

                    echo '<p style="font-family: arial;">Solution name: <a class="expand_suggested_solution" style="color: #295B7B;" href="#" data-suggestion_id="'.$suggested_solution_id.'"  data-problem_id="'.$problem_id.' ">'.$solution_name.'</a></p>';
                    echo '<p style="font-family: arial;">'.$solution.'</p>';
                    echo '<p style="color: #B77F37;">on '.$formatted_date.'</p>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
            }
    }
    else
    {
            echo '<p>There are no suggestions for future solutions yet.  Suggest a solution.</p>';
    }
}
```

You like the inline styling of HTML created on the server side? ;)

At both times, the HTML looks like this:

```
<p style="font-family: arial;">
Solution name:
<a class="expand_suggested_solution" data-problem_id="219" data-suggestion_id="75" href="#" style="color: #295B7B;">test1</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I tried to check very carefully whether there is an inconsistency between the html that gets displayed, but it seems it is displayed by the same code, which is leaving me pretty confused how that can happen that at one point it works, and at another point, something is off.

Comment: The href of the anchor is indeed set to # after filling out the form. I can't tell whether it's set via client script or server-side. A code sample would be helpful

Comment: @Derek Ok about to post the code that prints that stuff

Comment: Ok, looks like the links are created dynamically on the server-side. In that case, you may want do bind the events using jQuery live() to persist the event handlers to all elements (present and future)

Comment: @Derek Hunziker Oh yeah, the live functon!!! Just so I get it right, where exactly should it be and how? Thanks!!

Comment: @Derek just changed the bind function to live, and it actually still didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click handler the JS is setting display:none to the element with the click handler. This might take the element out of the dom and make it lose the click listener.

Can you change these lines,

```
document.getElementById("add_existing_suggestion").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("add_existing_suggestion").style.display = 'inline';
```

to

```
document.getElementById("add_existing_suggestion").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("add_existing_suggestion").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Comment: Interesting - didn't think about it.  Let me try.

Comment: just tried it but it didn't quite work. I am confused with how it is supposed to look like since my current click handler has another ajax call and a bunch of code inside it.  Could you help me understand how the whole thing would look like?

Comment: @GeekedOut I just updated my answer. I thought you were creating elements with JS, but you are creating all the elements and hiding the ones not being used. The issue is that the javascript doesn't wait for the html to register with the dom before running. Since the code for the click handler is before the html it fails to register

Comment: @sissnb ah i think i understood what you meant...trying one more thing

Comment: @sissnb btw, from what you can see in my js, isn't all my js and jquery inside the document.ready already?

Comment: @sissnb the entire js block is inside $(function(){

Comment: @GeekedOut I don't see it wrapped in a '$(document).ready(function(){//code here})' I see it wrapped in '$(function(){//code here})'

Comment: @sissnb the whole js is wrapped in $(function(){ which I was told is the equivalent of document.ready()  ...no?

Comment: @GeekedOut ah, yes it is. I have another guess

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4859/discussion-between-sissonb-and-geekedout)

Answer (score 1):

Without doing in-depth debugging, if it is appending a "#" to the end of the URL instead of running some JS behaviour, it is likely one of two things:

1. The click handler is no longer bound correctly.
2. You forgot to `return false;` in the click handler.

Does either of those sound possible?

Comment: let me try to see whether the click handler is no longer bounded correctly.  I am definitely returning false though.

Comment: yes you are right, the click handler isn't being called.  Not sure why though lol